# NuGet Package Installed successfully but I can't reference in code. SecurePages

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, nuget

Visual Studio 2012 Express Forms Application 
httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"

I just added the SecurePages module via NuGet. Everything seems fine. I have changed nothing but the provided SecurePagesConfig.cs can not reference the module:

secureUrls.IgnoreUrl(@"(.*).css");

Error   1   The name 'secureUrls' does not exist in the current context MyAppPath\App_Start\SecurePagesConfig.cs    20  13  MyApp

The .dll is in my bin folder,
the reference to the .dll is there,
I see the package installed in NuGet,
The reference is added to  in web.config

Any ideas?
Thanks

SecurePagesConfig.cs:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SecurePages;
using SecurePages.Infrastructure;
using SecurePages.Entities;
using SecurePages.Services;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System;

[assembly: WebActivator.PostApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MyWebApp.App_Start.SecurePagesConfig), "Start")]

namespace MyWebApp.App_Start {
    public static class SecurePagesConfig {
        public static void Start() {
            RegisterSecurePagesConfigurations();            
        }

public static void RegisterSecurePagesConfigurations() {
            //Ignore defaults
            secureUrls.IgnoreUrl(@"(.*)\.css");
            secureUrls.IgnoreUrl(@"(.*)\.js");
            secureUrls.IgnoreUrl(@"(.*)\.png");
            secureUrls.IgnoreUrl(@"(.*)\.jpg");
            secureUrls.IgnoreUrl(@"(.*)\.gif");

            // Securing a collection of pages with Regex
            //SecurePagesConfiguration.Urls.AddRegex(@"(.*)account", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline);

            //Securing a page by specifying its url
            //SecurePagesConfiguration.Urls.Add("/cart");

            //Registering a custom rule (Example for AppHarbor)
            //SecurePagesConfiguration.RegisterCustomMatchRule(c => string.Equals(c.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Proto"], "https", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));


            //For testing only.  By default, secure pages will ignore all request from localhost
            #if DEBUG
            SecurePagesConfiguration.IgnoreLocalRequests = false;

            //Optional
            //SecurePagesConfiguration.HttpRootUrl = "http://localhost:50535/";
            //SecurePagesConfiguration.HttpsRootUrl = "https://localhost:44300/";
            #endif
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the entire file.

Comment: Are you defining the using? My first research would say: SecurePages.Entities.

Comment: Hi,Yes:using System.Web.Mvc;
using SecurePages;
using SecurePages.Infrastructure;
using SecurePages.Entities;
using SecurePages.Services; and still secureUrls does not exist

Comment: Hi SLaks, which file? SecurePagesConfig.cs is unedited from the install; it can not resolve the first request  secureUrls.IgnoreUrl(@"(.*)\.css");

Comment: I added using to Entities and Services and still no joy.Latest SecurePagesConfig.cs posted. The name 'secureUrls' does not exist in the current context.